# Overriding a parent's form field with options?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a base class that is a Django form. The child class then inherits from the parent including all the fields, but I need to make changes to one of the parent's field option such as `label`, `required`, and etc.

Example:

```
class BaseForm(forms.Form):
    userid = forms.CharField(required=True)

class ChildForm(BaseForm):
    # I need to change the parent field option 
    userid = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing exactly what you should do.

It's particularly fitting in this case because that's the exact pattern for overriding `ModelForm` fields.

If you need to retain properties you don't know about / are outside your control (or what have you), you could override the `__init__` method and access the form fields via `self.fields['myfield']`

```
class ChildForm(BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChildForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['userid'].required = False
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with overriding in the constructor, since I do not want to retain the defaults set in the parent class.